CodeSign error while running ios app using ionic and capacitor using MacOS
I am new to ionic and capacitor. I use M1 Arm Macbook Pro to build my ionic with capacitor project
. I am getting this error after running my ionic project.
`warning: Run script build phase '[CP] Embed Pods Frameworks' will be run during every build because it does not
specify any outputs. To address this warning, either add output dependencies to the script phase, or configure
it to run in every build by unchecking "Based on dependency analysis" in the script phase. (in target 'App' from
project 'App')
** BUILD FAILED **
    The following build commands failed:
    CodeSign
    /Users/xxxxx/Documents/ionic-test/test-app/ios/DerivedData/1E05867E-44A2-491E-810D-FD509D552CF4/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/CapacitorCordova/Cordova.framework
    (in target 'CapacitorCordova' from project 'Pods')
    (1 failure)`

I apologize in advance if I left out any information. I am a newbie so any information is appreciated.
TIA
I followed a simple tutorial to learn this. Below is a list of all commands that I have used so far:
1)ionic cap sync ios
2)ionic cap build ios
3)ionic cap run ios

Did you ever figure this out?

Nope, this issue is persisting. I think the capacitor team is looking into it. I hope it gets fixed soon!
